# Uso do atributo ID nas tags <link>

Tags: html

É apropriado o uso do atributo ID nas tags ? Em quais casos eu poderia usá-lo?

Quais versões do HTML suportariam esse tipo de referência? Nesse caso, o ID tem sempre a função de seletor?

Em quais outras tags podemos usar ID e que não têm uso recorrente desse atributo como as ?

Essas dúvidas vêm de uma amostra de código HTML que eu estava vendo e que tinha o seguinte:

```
<link href="link/pro/css/file.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**É apropriado o uso do atributo ID nas tags ? Em quais casos eu poderia usá-lo?**

Sim é apropriado desde que haja apenas um elemento com a ID. Por isso, deve haver cuidado no seu uso. Hoje em dia, com o jQuery largamente aceito, é muito mais comum usar-se classes, mesmo para acessar elementos JavaScript, pois selecionar um elemento via classe é tão fácil quanto via ID:

**Via ID**:
`elemento = $("#id")`

**Via classe**: `elemento = $(".classe")`

**Quais versões do HTML suportariam esse tipo de referência? Nesse caso, o ID tem sempre a função de seletor?**

Todos os elementos HTML podem ter um ID. O HTML, por ser uma linguagem extremamente semântica, não imputa um sentido de funcionalidade diretamente, mas sim de significado. O ID identifica o elemento dentro do documento. As funcionalidades podem ser das mais diversas. Por exemplo, você poderia usar o ID para identificar até mesmo um produto no banco de dados:

`<li class="product" id="product-323"></li>`

Obs: note que eu usei um prefixo em vez de deixar o número puro. Isso pra evitar ao máximo a duplicação de IDs na página. Outro objeto, como por exemplo `<a id="category-323"></a>` poderia acabar tendo o mesmo atributo ID por acidente.